# <FIRMessaging/WARNING> Failed to subscribe to topic Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=5 “(null)”

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-notifications, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm not able to receive notifications in iOS. I coded my application in ionic framework and apparently Firebase doesn't officially support ionic. Any ideas on how to resolve the issue.

Here what I've done already:

1. The certificates have been created in apple dev account.
2. APNS key has been uploaded to the firebase console.
3. Ive included the `Google-Service-Info.plist` to my project folder.

Im asked for permission for notification when the app opens up but my test notification is not getting received by the app.

The error message is :

> Failed to subscribe to topic Error
>   Domain=com.google.fcm Code=5 “(null)”

Xcode version: 9.4.1

iOS target development version: 9.0

iOS testing version: 11.4

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

**Search** all of the "Google-Service-Info.plist"files in your project folders. You will see an old or default verison of "Google-Service-Info.plist". Then replace the old one with your own.
This is my problem in my project.

Second probability is you are putting the plist file in **wrong folder**. check it pls.

Comment: nice!! Save my life!
there are two Google-service-info.plist file. 
the true one is in (ios root)/Resources/Resources/